# tried php install and show error packcage php-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)

Tags: centos, php, yum, vagrant

I tried 「sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php73 install php-pdo php-mysql」in vagrant and show

```
              Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
   error: package: php-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
              Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
            install: httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
                httpd-mmn = 20051115
   error: package: php-mysqlnd-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
   error: package: php-cli-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
   error: package: php-cli-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
   error: package: php-json-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
   error: package: php-common-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
   error: package: php-pdo-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
   error: package: php-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
             Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)

   You couldn't try using--skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try runnning: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

PHP 7.3.17 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

I have no idea what i have to do.
Please give me advice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error: package: php-7.3.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php73)
   install: httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64 (@base)
```

You are trying to install **CentOS 7** packages on a **CentOS 6** distribution.

Of course, this cannot work.

Please follow carefully the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

Comment: Can i also resolve this problem by grade up CentOS6 to CentOS7 or CnetOS8?

Comment: Yes, in all cases, you have to use the proper set of packages packages matching the used distribution (as explained by the Wizard). Commands may be slightly different on C8

Comment: Thank you I completed by your answer !!